# How do I pass the record id in an update call to the Bulk API V1?

Tags: bulk-api

When I try to update records using the Bulk API V1, I receive a missing_argument statusCode with a 'Id not specified in an update call' message. I've been looking through the docs but I can't find where I should pass the missing id field.

Answer (score 1):

Your Bulk API job body must contain the `Id` field as a column alongside your other data columns. For example, if you're providing a CSV, you would have something like this for a Contact update job:

```
Id,FirstName,LastName,...
003xxxxxxxxxxxx,Joe,Schmoe...
```

There is a rarely-used facility in the Bulk API that allows you to map columns, but it's almost always easier to just send the right columns in the first place.